# How to check a database column for special sign

Tags: sql, sql-server, regex, t-sql

I want to check a column for a special sign with regular expression, but not all special sign. I want all sign that are not letter, number and not ,+.-& (blank) .I try this

```
where column like '%[^((a-z)(A-Z)(0-9)(,\+\.\-)(\&)( ))]%'
```

same like this

```
where column like '%[^0-9a-zA-Z ,\-+\.\& ]%'
```

But if I try this Statement, I get strings with - and speziell blank.

> result1: 't-est regex'
>
> result2: ' TestJ.  '

Have you any idea why?

Thx for the help.

Comment: Which dbms are you using? Those LIKE's don't look like ANSI SQL compliant.

Comment: Add some sample table data and the expected result - as formatted text, not images.

Comment: Look at the documentation for your database's LIKE operator, you will find either that it does not support regular expressions or if it does it requires the use of a different keyword.

Comment: I use Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio

Comment: Microsoft's `LIKE` does not support real regular expressions.

Comment: You're almost there. `LIKE` does not require or support escaping inside `[]` blocks (except the `]` character itself). `N'%[^0-9a-zA-Z ,+.& -]%'` should do what you want. (Putting the `-` at the end prevents it from being mistaken as a range operator.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [LIKE operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/like-transact-sql) isn't exactly using the regex syntax. 
It's way more simplified.

But some things are still possible.

This LIKE would get what you want:

```
where [column] like '%[^A-Za-z0-9 &.,+-]%'
```

Note that the class negation `^` does work.
And it's best to put a `-` at the end of a class. So it's not mistaken to be used for a range of characters.

There's no concept for capture groups in a LIKE, so the `(` and `)` were removed.
But if you also want the LIKE to ignore the brackets, just add them to the character class.
(even in regex you don't have capture groups inside a character class anyway)

The LIKE operation is case-insensitive when the COLLATION of the character field is case-insensitive.
Which seems to be the default on most databases.
So most of the times, a `LIKE '%[A-Z]%'` and `LIKE '%[A-Za-z]%'` would behave the same.

**Example snippet:**

```
-- using a Case-Sensitive collation for the varchar. 
declare @T table (id int identity(1,1), col varchar(30) COLLATE Latin1_General_CS_AS);

insert into @T (col) values 
('abc123'),
('ABC & 123'),
('abc123 &.,+-'),
('abc-123 #');

select * from @T where col like '%[^A-Za-z0-9 &.,+-]%';
```

**Returns:**

```
id  col
--  ---------
4   abc-123 #
```

Comment: "*The LIKE operation is case-insensitive*" - that is only true if the column uses a _CI collation.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Thanks for the reminder.  I'm so used to tables that only have CI varchars that I hadn't thought about that.  Fixed.